# How to copy contents of wl-clipboard into a Vim register?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, os-clipboard, wayland

I would like to swap content between my system clipboard and a Vim register.
I am missing one last piece of the puzzle, indicated below. Any thoughts?

```
map <Leader>" :call SwapBuffer()<CR>
function! SwapBuffer()
    let @t=@"                   "t := v
    call system("wl-paste", @") "v := c  <- out-of-order. have also tried non-special reg.
    call system("wl-copy", @t)  "c := t
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
map <Leader>" :call SwapBuffer()<CR>
function! SwapBuffer()
    let @t=@"                   "t := v
    let @" = system("wl-paste") "v := c
    call system("wl-copy", @t)  "c := t
endfunction
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an [edit] explaining what changes were made to the code and _why_.

Comment: @charleskong, Maybe could you accept your answer. It allows the question to rest.